# How to write this particular query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How to handle two condition on a single column ? Suppose my query is like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 'aa' AND ( title REGEXP 'foo' OR branch REGEXP 'bar')
```

I want to put condition on `title` that it shoud not be of the pattern `"test - // followed by any thing".`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `AND title != 'test - // followed by any thing'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NOT LIKE:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE title NOT LIKE 'test - %'
-- AND etc....
```